# Phpunit error "This build of PHPDBG does not support code coverage"

Tags: phpunit, phpdbg

I'm getting error "This build of PHPDBG does not support code coverage" when try to run phpunit with coverage with phpdbg. I found in PHAR line which generate this error:

```
        if (!\function_exists('PHPUnit\\phpdbg_start_oplog')) {
            throw new \PHPUnit\SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\RuntimeException('This build of PHPDBG does not support code coverage');
        }
```

Then i run and get this result:

```
prompt> ev function_exists('phpdbg_start_oplog');
1
```

As i undestand, problem is in namespace before phpdbg_start_oplog. So, why phpdbg_start_oplog is prefixed with PHPUnit namespace in PHAR?

PHPUnit 9.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 28 2019 11:16:02) ( NTS )

Answer (score 0):

You found a bug in PHPUnit (or PHP-Scoper, one of the tools involved in building the PHAR distribution of PHPUnit). [I opened a ticket for this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4211).